# make tooltip in jfreechart data points to appear quicker

Tags: tooltip, jfreechart

is there a way to make tooltip in jfreechart data points to appear quicker?  here's how I customize the tooltip:

```
    renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator(){
        public String generateToolTip(XYDataset dataset, int series, int item) {
           double y =dataset.getYValue(series, item);
           double x = dataset.getXValue(series, item);
           return x+" m, "+y+" %";
        }
    });
```

Comment: Quicker than what? Have you tried `setInitialDelay()`? Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 4):

ChartPanel.setInitialDelay(x) is the solution as commented above